# Returning - Java

Tags: java, return

I made this program in the main method, but now I have to transfer this code/logic into a method that has a return type of an `int`.

How can I do that so that the logic still works?

Thanks!

```
for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++)
    {   if(j % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("2");

    }   
        for(int i=2;i<=number;i++) 
        {
            if( i % 2==1)
                    System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Comment: @MitchWheat I can't just say return "2";

Comment: create a variable of type int........

Comment: how many values you want to return from your method?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I want to always return the 2. But I only want to return the i IF the condition (i%2) is true

Comment: @Lily you can't return the 2 and continue processing the method. When it returns, the method is finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getInt(int number){
for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++)
    {   if(j % 2 == 0)
            return 2;

    }   
        for(int i=2;i<=number;i++) 
        {
            if( i % 2==1)
                    return i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to change your prints to returns, and pass `number` to the method:

```
public int myMethod(int number) {
   for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++) {  
       if(j % 2 == 0)
           return 2;
   }

    for(int i=2;i<=number;i++)  {
        if( i % 2==1)
            return i;
    }
    // nothing found, return default
    return 0; // required by compller
}
```

Comment: side comment - Understood that you answered the question correctly. However, I think it's better to use a comment or variable, rather than `2`, to explain the purpose of the method. `Code Complete` recommends against **magic** numbers, such as `2` here. link - http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670

Comment: @KevinMeredith no no, I want to return something in the method. I can't ONLY return something in the loop

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I retract my statement on being correct here. The first loop will always return **2** since 2 % 2 is always 0.

Comment: @Bohemian it will always return 2 though

Answer (score 1):

```
public int myMethodName()
{
    for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++)
    {   if(j % 2 == 0)
            return j;
    }   
    for(int i=2;i<=number;i++) 
    {
        if( i % 2==1)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    return i; // I have no idea what you want to return though
}
```

Or (if you want to take in a parameter):

```
public int myMethodName(int x) // take in more parameters by using commas
{
    for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++)
    {   if(j % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("2");

    }   
    for(int i=2;i<=number;i++) 
    {
        if( i % 2==1)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    return i; // I have no idea what you want to return though
}
```

To call your method in another method, do it like this:

```
int x = myMethodName();
```

or perhaps you want to pass it a parameter:

```
int y = 5; 
int x = myMethodName(y);
```

Comment: you are missing return statement please check it compilation error.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Wow. I can't believe I did that. Oops. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int methodName()
{
    //Your Code Here
     return AN_INTEGER_HERE; //
}
```

Then use `methodName();` in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to write second `for loop` as the control always `return` from first `for loop`.
  because `2%2 == 0` always `true`.

```
public int getFirstValue()
{
  for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++)
        {   if(j % 2 == 0)
             return j;    
        }
}
```

but if you want to write another method for second `for loop` try this:

```
public int getSecondValue(int number)
   {
       for(int i=2;i<=number;i++) 
       {
        if( i % 2==1)
               return i;
       }
   }
```